# Is it possible to get the index (start position) for the selected text in a WebBrowser control?

Tags: .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I would like to get the index (start position) for the selected text in a WebBrowser control. Similar to the index you would get when doing a regular expression search.

I want to get the "line and column number" of the selected text. These can be determined based on the index of the selection.

I have tried using an IHTMLTxtRange in combination with IDisplayServices/IHTMLCaret but the best i can get are point locations.

If the "point locations" can be converted to a character position that would also work.

What would be the easiest way of doing this?

Comment: Another approach might be to get the structural location (position) of the html element in the selection.

Comment: How would you define row and column numbers in a HTML document? Like an absolutely positioned one?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question to make it clearer what i am looking for. I changed "line and column number" to "index (start position)".

Answer (score 2):

You can try MoveMarkupPointerToCaret and IMarkupPointer::Left or IMarkupPointer2::GetMarkupPosition to inspect the caret's location.

Comment: I tried using the MoveMarkupPointerToCaret function but did not manage to get the results i was looking for. I guess need to spend some more time on it. I ended up doing something else for now (see added answer)

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix i ended up using the MouseUp event of an extended WebBrowser control to get the cursor position. I used this to get the Element at the current clicked/selected text in the WebBrowser control.

```
Dim ScreenCoord As New Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y)
Dim BrowserCoord As Point = webBrowser1.PointToClient(ScreenCoord)
Dim elem As HtmlElement = webbrowser1.Document.GetElementFromPoint(BrowserCoord)
```

I used a helper function to get the index of the element at the cursor location.

```
Function getIndexforElement(elem As htmlElement, browser As webbrowser) As Integer
    Dim page as mshtml.HTMLdocument
    Dim Elements as mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim elemCount As Integer = 0
    page = browser.document.Domdocument
    elements = page.getElementsByTagName(elem.TagName)
    For Each element As mshtml.IHTMLElement In elements
        elemCount = elemCount + 1
        If (elem.OffsetRectangle.Top = element.offsetTop) And (elem.OffsetRectangle.Left = element.offsetLeft) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If elemCount > 0 Then
        Dim matches as MatchCollection = regex.Matches(browser.DocumentText,"<" & elem.TagName,regexoptions.IgnoreCase Or regexoptions.Multiline)
        Return matches(elemCount-1).Index + 1
    Else
        Return 0
    End If  
End Function
```

Having the index of the element a simple regular expression could be used to find the line number in the original html file.

```
Function getLineNumber(textIn As String, index As Integer) As Integer
    textIn = textIn.Replace(VbCrLf,VbLf)
    Dim line as Integer = regex.Matches(textIn.Substring(0,index),"\n",RegexOptions.Multiline).Count + 1                                                                                 
    If line < 1 Then line = 1
    Return line
End Function
```